# Html Layout problems...

Tags: html, css

Ok so i have this Html + Css structure... all I want is to have the four div's in one line.

can anybody take a look and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ynnfmo5/

`<body>
    <div class="listItem">
        <div id="detailsName" class="detailsName">
        </div>
        <div class="detailsDate">
        </div>
        <div class="status">
        </div>
        <div class="button">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`

`    .listItem{
    position:absolute;
    display: table;
    padding:3px;
    width:70%;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #28b4ea;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-style: none;
    min-height:60px;
}

```
.listItem .detailsName{
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    left:0px;
    height:56px;
    min-height: 56px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.listItem .detailsDate{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    display: table-cell;
    height:56px;
    width:150px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.listItem .status{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    display: table-cell;
    height:56px;
    width:150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.listItem .button{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    display: table-cell;
    height:56px;
    width:150px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}`
```

Comment: is it what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/0ynnfmo5/1/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai first div must have the dynamic width and the rest must have fixed width

Comment: @Paulie_D first div must have the dynamic width and the rest must have fixed width

Comment: @Relix just remove 100% width and assigned to auto. https://jsfiddle.net/0ynnfmo5/4/

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for your response ... that was what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `display:table-cell` **and** `float`

```css
.listItem {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #28b4ea;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-style: none;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.listItem .detailsName {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 56px;
  min-height: 56px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.listItem .detailsDate {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 56px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.listItem .status {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 56px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.listItem .button {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 56px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="listItem">
  <div id="detailsName" class="detailsName"></div>
  <div class="detailsDate"></div>
  <div class="status"></div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Obviously at some point the wrapping div won't be wide enough for all the divs (such as in the mini-view below) so you'd need media queries to adjust as required..